# YouTube Video API Time Out

Tags: youtube-api, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am using the Xamarin Mono for Android Google API binding. I receive an HTTP 308 error, which is basically a timeout, when I upload a video that's larger than 75 MB. I am unable to cast my videosInsertRequest.RequestFactory to GDataRequestFactory and set the time out. No GDataRequestFactory exists. The request factory is of type ICreateHttp and it's create method returns a HttpWebRequest. Is there another way to set the YouTubeRequest's time out property or upload the videos another way?

```
                GoogleAuthenticator auth2;

                YoutubeService yt = new YoutubeService (auth2);

                string name = String.Format("{0} {1}", etStatusUpdate.Text, DateTime.Now.ToString());
                var videosInsertRequest = yt.Videos.Insert (Helpers.MakeVideo (name, etStatusUpdate.Text), "snippet,statistics,status", MakeVideoFileStream (), VIDEO_FILE_FORMAT);

               //((GDataRequestFactory)videosInsertRequest.RequestFactory).Timeout = 9999999;

                videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
                videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/).

[YouTube Direct Lite](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android/blob/master/src/com/google/ytdl/ResumableUpload.java) project has uploads for Android.

Comment: Hi, is this contained in Xamarin's implementation? I have no MediaHttp code.